# How to get latest status or updates from facebook page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a asp.net web application in which I have to show top 10 latest **status or updates** of facebook page that I have created for client.
For Eg : If I added a status that **Mr X will organise the show** on my FB page then this status will be shown on my website under the Recent update tab automatically.

I have searched google but at the end I land on to the FB developers page where I am getting confused between the functionality for fetching data from the page.

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could just use the

```
/{page_id}/posts?limit=10
```

for that. Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed/

I'd recommend that you generate a Page Access Token as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens and use this for your requests.